# Blackberry playbook integrattion problem 

Tags: emulation, blackberry-playbook

Hi all i have problem to intagrate bb playbook air sdk to adobe flash builder 40.0.0. when i run Helloworld program to my bb playbook Emulator ,i am not getting bb playbook option on my run>debug>other .so what can i co for that ?  and can we develop bb playbook application in java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java sdk is not yet available for the PlayBook. But RIM will release it later this year, though there have been no release date communicated yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

For Playbook development (AIR) you need at least [Flash Builder 4.5](http://www.adobe.com/go/try_flashbuilder/)